# Too much space between text and tcolorbox

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox

I am using tcolorbox and the spacing before the second tcolorbox is messed up, that is only 3 lines of text are there before the box.

I tried to type a document as a MWE, but I think the only way to do so is to type all 3 pages of my text since if I delete everything but the text on the page with spacing issues, the spacing look good.

Should I try and make a MWE with 3 pages then?

Thanks

I have finally created a MWE that reproduces the issue using the lipsum package. While this is not exactly the same as what I experienced (in my full document, the text starting with "Come, let us worship" up until the tcolorbox is spread over an entire page), this does show the spacing issue I mentioned.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{%
mytitle/.style={%
    enhanced,
    overlay={
        \node [rotate=90, anchor=south, fill=tcbcolframe!25] at (frame.west) {\itshape #1};
    },
},
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
mytitle={#2},
toprule=0pt,
bottomrule=0pt,
rightrule=0pt,
sharp corners,
#1
}

%opening
\title{Prayerbook Test}

\author{}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \lipsum[1-4]

    \section*{Morning Troparia, Tone 2}

    Having risen from sleep, I thank Thee, O Holy Trinity, 
for in the abundance of Thy goodness and Thy
patience, Thou hast not become angry with me for
my laziness and sinfulness, nor hast Thou destroyed
me together with mine iniquities. Instead, in Thy
usual love for mankind, Thou hast raised me from
the gloominess of sleep, that I might rise up early
and glorify Thy power. Enlighten now the eyes of
my mind and open Thou my lips, that I might come
to learn Thy words, understand Thy commandments, 
accomplish Thy will, glorify Thee in heart-
felt confession, and praise Thine All-holy Name, of
the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit, now and ever, and
unto ages of ages. Amen.\\

Come, let us worship God our King!\\

Come, let us worship and fall down before Christ, our King and our God!\\

Come, let us worship and fall down before Christ Himself, our King and our God!\\

\section*{The Hexapsalms (The Six Psalms)}

\begin{mybox}[colframe=blue]{Monday Morning}

\subsection*{Psalm 3}

O Lord, why are they so many many that afflict me?
Many are they who rise up against me.
Many are they who say to my soul, ``There is no help for him in his God.''
But Thou, O Lord, art my defender; Thou art my glory, and the lifter up of my head.\\

I cried unto the Lord with my voice, and He heard me out of His holy hill.
I laid me down and slept; and I rose up again,
For the Lord sustained me.
I will not be afraid of the ten thousand that have surrounded themselves against me.\\

Arise, O Lord, and save me, O my God!
For Thou hast smitten all mine enemies upon the cheek,
Thou hast broken the teeth of the ungodly.
Salvation is of the Lord -- Thy blessing is upon Thy people.

\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Sorry about the lack of clarity in my initial post.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you get the wrong output by having a `\clearpage` just before the page in question?  What do you mean by "messed up"?  Your title indicates too much space.  How much text is there before the first tcolorbox, how tall is that tcolorbox, how much text is before the second tcolorbox, how tall is that tcolorbox, how much text comes afterward?

Comment: This MWE is not always needed, but this is not the case. Use the package `lipsum` to produce dummy text, so you can easily add as many sentences and paragraphs as you need to reproduce the issue with a few commands. On the other hand, only guessing, probably the same spacing problem arise if you change the tcolorboxes  by tabulars or minipages with similar sizes in the MWE. In that case, relieve us to have to see the code of tcolorbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  make a `tcolorbox` breakable across multiple pages to use the space left in the first page. For your example use `\usepackage[skins, breakable]{tcolorbox}` and add  the `breakable` parameter to `tcbset`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<

\tcbset{% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
    mytitle/.style={%
        enhanced,
        overlay={
            \node [rotate=90, anchor=south, fill=tcbcolframe!25] at (frame.west) {\itshape #1};
        },
    },
breakable 
}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
    mytitle={#2},
    toprule=0pt,
    bottomrule=0pt,
    rightrule=0pt,
    sharp corners,
    #1
}

%opening
\title{Prayerbook Test}

\author{}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \lipsum[1-4]
    
    \section*{Morning Troparia, Tone 2}
    
    Having risen from sleep, I thank Thee, O Holy Trinity, 
    for in the abundance of Thy goodness and Thy
    patience, Thou hast not become angry with me for
    my laziness and sinfulness, nor hast Thou destroyed
    me together with mine iniquities. Instead, in Thy
    usual love for mankind, Thou hast raised me from
    the gloominess of sleep, that I might rise up early
    and glorify Thy power. Enlighten now the eyes of
    my mind and open Thou my lips, that I might come
    to learn Thy words, understand Thy commandments, 
    accomplish Thy will, glorify Thee in heart-
    felt confession, and praise Thine All-holy Name, of
    the Father, Son, and Holy Spirit, now and ever, and
    unto ages of ages. Amen.\\
    
    Come, let us worship God our King!\\
    
    Come, let us worship and fall down before Christ, our King and our God!\\
    
    Come, let us worship and fall down before Christ Himself, our King and our God!\\
    
    \section*{The Hexapsalms (The Six Psalms)}
    
    \begin{mybox}[colframe=blue]{Monday Morning}
        
        \subsection*{Psalm 3}
        
        O Lord, why are they so many many that afflict me?
        Many are they who rise up against me.
        Many are they who say to my soul, ``There is no help for him in his God.''
        But Thou, O Lord, art my defender; Thou art my glory, and the lifter up of my head.\\
        
        I cried unto the Lord with my voice, and He heard me out of His holy hill.
        I laid me down and slept; and I rose up again,
        For the Lord sustained me.
        I will not be afraid of the ten thousand that have surrounded themselves against me.\\
        
        Arise, O Lord, and save me, O my God!
        For Thou hast smitten all mine enemies upon the cheek,
        Thou hast broken the teeth of the ungodly.
        Salvation is of the Lord -- Thy blessing is upon Thy people.
        
    \end{mybox}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great thank you!

Comment: I am now trying to use \titlesec to modify my \section and other headers, but keep getting the error: illegal parameter number in definition of \ttlf@section in \titlespacing. I am wanting to use:    '\titleformat{\section}
{\centering\normalfont\Large\bfseries\textcolor{red}{#1}}{}{16pt}{\Large}
\titlespacing{\section}
{0pt}{18pt}{14pt}'